# How to run a local PHP file (in PC) from another PHP file (Hosted on linux server)

Tags: php

In my pc i have installed XAMPP and running a PHP file which communication to an external device which is connected to PC.

Now i want to call local PHP file (EX: http://localhost/MY_PROJECT/X.PHP) from another PHP file which is hosted in a linux server.

In my local PHP file i am returning some JSON data. I have tried calling it from POSTMAN and it is working as expected. But when i tried to call it from server i am not getting any response.

Am i missing something here. Do i need to change and config in .ini file or there is any specific way to do this.?

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: You need to use a tunneling service that exposes your localhost to the internet, like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: @Accountantم Thanks for your suggestion. As other possible way..?

Comment: Yeah, you can configure your router to open the webserver ports`80/443` for listening and route this traffic to your your PC's local IP, and connect from your server to your PC on your PC public IP, I never tried it myself though. I think this is a googable issue, many people tried this before you.